# Creating Data Elevation Model from two sources

Tags: dem

I have 2 Data Elevation Models ( Aster with 30 m resolution and a DEM obtained by stereo with 4 m resolution ).

Unfortunatly the DEM with high resolution contains a lot of no data value and some values with low accuracy. So, I want to use the two DEMs and extract one DEM with high accuracy. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can subsample aster to 4 m and combine both DEMs using simple IF ELSE statements.

Note that no new information will be created in the subsampling.